# is it possible to use one progressbar for several variable length processes?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

In my current situation i have a winform application dat generates random data for the several data types user selects.
The user can olso select how many rows must be generated, for the generation i use several functions called within a button_click method.
The ammount of rows and the ammount of columns per row are variable in length.
Now my question is it possible to make one progressbar for the entire progress?
This is my first C# project i make myself i already found information about a background worker but i can not find information if my question is possible.
Hope somewhane can help me and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, yes you can update the value of your one `ProgressBar` from within different parts of your code.

If you want to assign different values to different actions, just make a method of sorts. For example:

Assuming `myProgressBar.Maximum = rowCount + columnCount;`

```
public void UpdateProgressBar(int i)
{
   if(myProgressBar.Value < myProgressBar.Maximum)
   {
      if(myProgressBar + i > myProgressBar.Maximum)
          myProgressBar.Value = myProgressBar.Maximum;
      else myProgressBar.Value += i;
   }
   myProgressBar.Update();
}
```

likewise, you would call similar code in any events you would like to reflect in your `ProgressBar`, like adding or removing rows or button clicks.

Look at some tutorials about `BackGroundWorker`, that'll keep your UI responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can could how many rows and columns there are . And then set the progressBar1.Maximum  to row + column and when program in background worker do one column you increase progressBar1.Value += 1; . All that must be in backgroundWorker so that progressBar will run smooth.

Answer (score 0):

The [ProgressBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.value%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) has a member named "Value". If you know how many items will be created, you can set it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without background worker. Use Minimum, Maximum and Value property of progress bar to achieve this. Set progressbar1.Maximum to row's count and inside row for loop, increase value by 1.

```
progressBar1.Minimum = 1;
progressBar1.Maximum = Rows.Count;

progressBar1.Value = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= Row.Count; i++)
{
  progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value + 1;
  ...
  ... do your code
  ...
```